# App signs in successfully but crashes when it tries to use the API if the user deletes their data from the Play Games app

Tags: android, google-play-games

Actual:

1. The user signs in to Play Games in my app
2. The user deletes all their game data through the Play Games app
3. The user opens my app again
4. My attempts a silent sign in
5. The silent sign in succeeds
6. I use the provided GoogleSignInAccount to initialize an
   AchievementsClient
7. I attempt use the AchievementsClient to get all the users
   achievements The app crashes with ApiException: 26504: The user must
   be signed in to make this API call.

Expected:
The silent sign in should fail, or at the very least I should get CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED.

Rarely, it does actually give CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED, but almost every time, it gives the first error I mentioned.

Clearing the apps data and cache after deleting data in Play Games causes the initial silent sign in to fail (as it should), which triggers the interactive sign in, which completes successfully. It is unclear to me as to why clearing the apps cache fixes the silent sign in allowing it to fail as expected, since I am not intentionally saving any data about the users signed in state.

Comment: I have the same exactly problem. Ever figured out why?

Comment: I don't think so / I don't remember. Sorry

Comment: @MalithLakshan did you ever figure out this problem? I'm having a related problem except with real time multiplayer. My achievements are working fine and I've only gotten this error while working with the multiplayer.

Comment: I've found a solution to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56463302/5434860 This may or may not help you.